# What is different between join/get and allOf in completable future?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, parallel-processing, completable-future

If allOf in the documentation indicates that it's " a static method of the CompletableFuture class. It returns a new CompletableFuture object when all of the specified CompletableFutures are complete" and join is " a static method of the CompletableFuture class. It returns a new CompletableFuture object when all of the specified CompletableFutures are complete" so why should I use both? can I use allOf only? or join only? or they work together.

My use case is I'm calling n of tasks in async using completableFuture but I want to combile the results of them together.

Comment: What documentation are you looking at?  [The documentation of CompletableFuture.join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join()) does not say those things.  It’s a good idea to use the official documentation before relying on any self-proclaimed gurus or teachers.

Answer (score 1):

[`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join--) is **not** a static method. It's a blocking call that waits for the `CompletableFuture` to finish its calculation and return the result.

[`allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) is a non-blocking static method that returns a new `CompletableFuture` that "wraps" the `CompletableFutures` passed to it and itself completes when all of the `CompletableFutures` passed to it have completed.

Comment: okay what if the method that uses allOf() has finished before allOf gets complete I mean before  CompletableFutures passed to it completes in that case I still didn't get the results of each completeableFuture because allOf wrapper CompletableFuture  doesn't have the all results

Comment: like this
 CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Result 1");
        CompletableFuture<String> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Result 2");
        CompletableFuture<String> future3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Result 3");

        CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, future3);
        
        allFutures.join();

Comment: can I use join before allOf to gurantee that allFutures  will contain a completed CompletableFutures ?

Comment: `allOf` gives you a CompletableFuture.  You have to handle it like a CompletableFuture!  Either wait for it to complete, or hook up an action that will run when it does complete. `join` is one way to wait for it to complete.

Comment: Using 'join before allOf' is (apart from considerations of whether it would actually work) pointless, because you've already got the results from everything you joined.

Comment: Imagine a case when I didn't use join but I used allOf and of the tasks took like 2 minutes while all of the rest tasks took much less than that so at some momenet I will have allFutures but it's not complete, if I have used join before allOf I guarantee that allFutures will be awlays completed?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanIbrahim, Re, "Imagine a case where..." Please, Don't ask us to imagine it. Ask a _new_ question (your question about `join` vs. `allOf` has a perfectly good answer right here) and _include the actual source code that you are trying to understand._ Then, everybody will be able to see exactly what situation you are asking about, and it's more likely that somebody will be able to help you to understand it.

Comment: Maybe this answer should spell it out explicitly: *`allOf` does not block the caller/does not wait for any future to complete. All it does, is returning a new future*

Comment: @Holger wording amended

Answer (score 0):

You are very wrong about `join`.  Per the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join()):

```
public T join() 

Returns the result value when complete, or throws an (unchecked)
exception if completed exceptionally. To better conform 
with the  use of common functional forms, if a computation
involved in the  completion of this CompletableFuture threw
an exception, this  method throws an (unchecked)
CompletionException with the underlying exception as its cause. 

Returns:  
the result value  

Throws: 
CancellationException - if the computation was cancelled 
CompletionException - if this future completed exceptionally 
              or a completion computation threw an exception
```

So - amongst the differences are:

- The number of futures involved: one versus many
- Whether the call waits for completion
- Return value - the result, versus another completeable future.
- The handling of exceptions.

i.e., they are hardly comparable at all.